# global namespace function not available in namespaced class constructor

Tags: php, wordpress

WordPress has global functions such as wp_get_current_user(), which **I can call in class methods** that are under different namespaces with `\wp_get_current_user`. However **I'm not able to do so either in the class constructor or setting it to a variable** (class attributes such as `$user = \wp_get_current_user`). I'm guessing there's a PHP rule that I'm not aware of here?

For example,

```
namespace App;
class User{

    //this doesn't work **I found that this is because we have to initialize the variables with constants (expressions aren't allowed**
    $user = \wp_get_current_user(); 

    function __construct(){
        //this also doesn't work
        $this->user = \wp_get_current_user();

        $this->init();
    }

    function init(){
        //this works
        $this->user = \wp_get_current_user();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reason for not being able to call this method in the plugins constructor's is because wp_get_current_user() is defined in the pluggable.php file (the functions in there can be overridden if we choose to) , which is loaded after all the plugins. So a solution would be to call this function inside a class method that's registered to WordPress hooks (add_action, ..filter).

Answer (score 0):

wp_get_current_user() is a pluggable function in /wp-includes/pluggable.php, you use it as a function call like this:

```
<?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); ?>
```

Comment: hi thanks for answering, however that's not what I'm asking. I've edited my original post to describe the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can call the wp_get_current_user() from a global context and pass its value as an argument to the User class constructor. You should then be able to access the current user from within your class